# Origin not visible in perspective projection

Tags: origin

I am new to blender. I am running blender 3.4.1 (from Debian repos) on Debian 12.
If I start from scratch (*New File > General*) I won't see the origin (orange dot) of the activated cube, although viewport overlay *Origins* is checked. Also checking *Origins(All)* does not help.

Only when I change to orthographic projection I see the orange dot as expected. It disappears again when changing projection back to *Perspective*.

[image: Origin only visible in orthographic projection]

Any idea why?

Behaviour is not any different in Blender 3.6.9 from Blender's project home page.
I also tried to reset blender's preferences by deleting `~/.config/blender/` which did not help either.

Comment: What do you mean by "perspective projection? - Switching between views with the '5' key on the numpad or hitting the R/H grid icon in the 3D view, or something else? - I can't check in Linux because I use Windows, but the origin dot should be in the centre of the 3D cursor in both views with a default cube added in Object mode.

Comment: Hi John!
I edited my original post. Please look at the screenshots.
Thank you.

Comment: yes, weird, it looks like a bug

Comment: @moonboots Agreed, but if it's the same with 3.4.1 and 3.6.8 (3.6.9 doesn't exist yet!) I'd go for a graphics driver problem personally.

Comment: ... I was using the 3.6.9 release candidate from https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay. the assumption of @John Eason is correct.
It seems to be a driver issue.
I am using an nVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti card and I am using the nouveau driver, which is the most conservative accelerating driver for the nVidia-cards.
After blacklisting (=disabling) the driver, the problem does not appear any longer.
Strange that the driver fails with such a relative minor and unrelated effect.

As generally disabling the driver system-wide is not favourable, does blender offer a startup-option to not use acceleration?

Comment: You can disable the GPU for rendering but I doubt you could (or would want to) disable it for normal viewport operations.